# How to make database design for multiple information included table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

How to design one to one database table?

I have a report that gets data from users. But report includes multiple type of records.

Report includes following information:

- Customer information (name, age, city, ...)
- Company information (name, address, coutry, year, ...)
- Device information (devname, code, serialnumber,...)
- Approve information (who_approved, date, ..)

and more information.

So I have a report table. But should create only one report table and add all columns in this table?

Or should I create a `Reports` table and `CustomerInformation, CompanyInformation, DeviceInformation, ApproveInformation` and one to one relationships?

Comment: This is just far too broad and vague for a good answer. But it seems you don't have a database design issue - rather you have a report design / coding issue. Most reporting tools can have multiple sources of information and can nest sub-reports within reports.

Comment: don't think of it as a report, it may be another name. The actual problem is how can I make. I'm really wondering if you have any ideas

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should know if you are going with MYSQL or MongoDB.
In MYSQL, it is not a good approach to use clustered table. While, in MongoDB, using clustered table is always an option.

Anyways, normalizing the database is the best approach. Which means, you should make more tables if possible but avoid data redundancy

Comment: All tables will have only one row for each report. So I asked if I am in true way.